# How to return JSON data from an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a JSON object I am returning from the database.  It is formatted correctly.  I am trying to access the data in it with an AJAX call.  Here is my AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url('find_representatives/find_rep_by_address/get_coordinates'); ?>', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
             alert(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
             alert(status);
        }
});
```

I have '' in my data because I am looking for all of the data.  I tried putting 'id' there (there is an ID in my JSON object, but the function stopped working when I did that.  When I alert 'data' I get an object, but where I alert 'data.id' I get 'undefined.'  What am I doing wrong?  This is my first AJAX call.  The URL is valid.  I checked.

Comment: Are you returning application/json as the Content-Type?

Comment: Open up your browser's debugger, look at the NET tab and sniff the response from the server. See what you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `data[0]` and see what you get in an alert...been there i think this will help you

Comment: This assumes he's getting an array back, which doesn't appear to be the case.  Even so, if data[0] is an object, what good is an alert?

Answer (score 7):

```
data: '{}',
```

This sends an empty data object to the server and works around some issues where sending empty data (not including the `data` at all) causes issues.

One other thing I have seen is not setting:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

One easy way to "debug" data visually is to include json2.js and do (in the success function):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: `$http.post("Status.aspx/MyData", {})` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
$.getJSON(<?php echo site_url('find_representatives/find_rep_by_address/get_coordinates'); ?>, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I tried that and was having similar problems.  I think it was because the JSON data was an array of arrays.

Comment: Why?  DataType is json.  This is functionally equivalent.

Comment: Console.log it and then inspect the data. You might have to use `data[0]` if it is JSONP

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information to answer this question properly.

If you're trying to debug with 'Alert' though, you're in trouble.

Instead of 'alert(data)', try 'console.log(data)', assuming you're using FireBug or the Inspector (Chrome, Safari).

Data may be several kinds of things, generally an object.  So, alerting it won't do much for you, unless you turn it into a string first.

You can also use the network panels to see what data is coming over the wire, or you can use something like Fiddler or HTTPScoop to figure out what is coming back from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` key here is the one you want to send to the server (if any):

```
data: '',
```

But the `data` argument inside the callbacks is what you receive back from the server:

```
success: function(data, status, xhr) {
    alert(data);
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(status);
}
```

When you use `dataType: 'json'`, you are telling jQuery that you are expecting JSON back from the server. So, are you outputting valid JSON from PHP (e.g., with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode))? If so, your code should work.